# How to add ios source dependency to Flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, flutter, podspec, flutter-plugin, podfile

I have created a Flutter plugin and this is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'sdksso'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

Then I need to add ios source, in Flutter project I would write `source 'https://<path>/podspecs.git'` in Podfile.
How to add ios source to Flutter plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Open iOS folder inside your plugin
2. look for plugin_name.podspec
3. After the line `s.dependency 'Flutter'` in podspec, add your ios dependencies like below.

[image]